# Trying to replace dashes in url rewrite

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I want to change the URL From

```
example.com/shows/2013-car-show-pictures-set
```

to

```
example.com/pics/2013+car+show+pictures+set
```

How do i replace all the dashes using rewrite?

```
RewriteRule ^shows/(.*)/$       /pics/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Is `car-show-pictures-set` text that can vary in the number of words it contains?

Comment: umm dunno what language but there should be a replaceAll function no? whichc takes in a certain char?

Comment: This question has some good answers about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105009/mod-rewrite-replace-all-underscore-with-hyphen