# encode and slash replace for HTTP_HOST and REQUEST_URI in mod_rewrite .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have created `.htaccess` file like this, here I am searching for `DB` string, if uri contains `DB` string then write complete `uri` to variable `url` and redirect, so far I tried this.. I don't know much about mod_rewrite and htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# If URI contains string DB then encode http_host and request uri and 
# send to http://host.domain.org/site2/index.php with new variable url=encodedstring

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /DB/
RewriteRule ^ http://host.domain.org/site2/index.php?url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE]
```

Suppose if my url is

```
  http://host.domain.org/site2/DB/process.php?name=x&y=10
```

I would like url variable to be this

```
 $ echo 'http://host.domain.org/site2/DB/process.php?name=x&y=10' | base64 
 aHR0cDovL2hvc3QuZG9tYWluLm9yZy9zaXRlMi9EQi9wcm9jZXNzLnBocD9uYW1lPXgmeT0xMAo=
```

I want url should be like this

```
 http://host.domain.org/site2/index.php?url=aHR0cDovL2hvc3QuZG9tYWluLm9yZy9zaXRlMi9EQi9wcm9jZXNzLnBocD9uYW1lPXgmeT0xMAo=
```

I don't know this is possible or not in .htaccess kindly someone help me

I even tried to replace all slashes to hypen like this at last

```
slash.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed -u 's/\//-/g'
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /DB/
RewriteMap slash prg:/var/www/virtual/slash.sh
http://host.domain.org/site2/index.php?url="${slash:%{HTTP_HOST}}${slash:%{REQUEST_URI}}" [L]
```

Suppose if my url is

```
  http://host.domain.org/site2/DB/process.php?name=x&y=10
```

I want url should be like this

```
 http://host.domain.org/site2/index.php?url="http:--host.domain.org-site2-DB-process.php?name=x&y=10"
```

I received an error 500 Internal Server error

So finally neither base64 nor slash replace worked for me.. its my hard luck

Thanks.

Comment: But why do you need base64 encoded URL in query parameter?

Comment: At first I tried to replace all slash to hyphen it did not work, so thought base64 may be good, I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105009/mod-rewrite-replace-all-underscore-with-hyphen hard luck did not work

Comment: I will create iframe using that url

Comment: @anubhava Please help me I saw you helped thousands of people.. please do favour for me also..

Comment: I can give you a rule to convert slash to hyphen. But you need to rephrase your question and show your original and expected URLs.

Comment: Sure I will modify now

Comment: @anubhava I have modified my post please look into it

Comment: ok give me some time, I need to rush for a meeting. I will provide my answer after coming back to my computer.

Comment: @anubhava : Ok thank you I will be waiting for you.

Comment: note that Rewritemap cannot be used in a `.htaccess` file, you need access to apache configuration directly (like a `Directory` section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules are tricky but since your requirement is as such I am providing you an answer here.

Please this in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site2/DB/process\.php$ /site2/index.php/http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/site2/index.php)/([^/]*)/([^/]*/.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2-%3 [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/site2/index.php)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ %1?url=%2-%3 [L,NE,QSA,R=302]
```

This will redirect a URI like this: `/site2/DB/process.php?name=x&y=10`

to this: `/site2/index.php?url=http:--www.localhost-site2-DB-process.php&name=x&y=10`

Thus replacing all the hyphens by `-` in the `url` query parameter.